# Remove extra GROUP BY in SQL query in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the following model:

```
class Statistics(models.Model):
    game_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='gameid', primary_key=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    servers = models.IntegerField()
    users = models.IntegerField()
```

I have legacy postgre database with custom database function `datediff_hours`. 
To use this function in django I create the following class:

```
from django.db.models import Func


class DateDiffHoursFunc(Func):
    function = 'datediff_hours'
```

Now I construct the actual query:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Value, F

query = Statistics.objects.values('time').filter(game_id=1).\
        annotate(users_sum=Sum('users', distinct=True)).\
        annotate(timestamp=DateDiffHoursFunc(Value(datetime(2016, 5, 26)), F('time'))).\
        values('users_sum', 'timestamp')
```

And the query I get:

```
>>> print(query.query)

SELECT 
     SUM(`statistics`.`users`) AS `users_sum`, 
     datediff_hours(2013-04-01 00:00:00, `statistics`.`time`) AS `timestamp`
FROM `statistics` WHERE `statistics`.`gameid` = 12 
GROUP BY `statistics`.`time`, datediff_hours(2013-04-01 00:00:00, `statistics`.`time`) 
ORDER BY NULL
```

But what I need grouping only by `time`, like this:

```
SELECT 
     SUM(`statistics`.`users`) AS `users_sum`, 
     datediff_hours(2013-04-01 00:00:00, `statistics`.`time`) AS `timestamp`
FROM `statistics` WHERE `statistics`.`gameid` = 12 
GROUP BY `statistics`.`time`) 
ORDER BY NULL
```

How can I restrict grouping only by `time`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution eventually was to switch to `SqlAlchemy` for complex queries. This package worked for me well - [Aldjemy](https://github.com/Deepwalker/aldjemy)

Comment: I suffered a lot with sqlalchemy, Django's orm is more advanced in every aspect that you could find (most notably in documentation and code updates)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Raw SQL?

```
    query = Statistics.objects.values('time').filter(game_id=1).\
            annotate(users_sum=Sum('users', distinct=True)).\
            annotate(timestamp=DateDiffHoursFunc(Value(datetime(2016, 05, 26)), F('time'))).\
            values('users_sum', 'timestamp').query
    query.group_by = ['time']
    objs = QuerySet(query=query, models=Statistics)
```

Its a bit risky solution, but try it.